# Web Form Filler With Custom Lists

Tags: browser, browser-addons

I am looking for a web form filler that will allow me to define custom pick-lists for certain fields.

My company has an internal web app for managing product features and bugs. When I am adding a new item, I get a web form to enter in the required information. There is a field when I can type in a specific numeric ID.

I use a set of specific IDs for my work.

I'd like to have an add-on that will bring up my custom list of IDs, so I can select the one I want to go into that field.

Do you know of a tool/add-on that can do this?

Comment: There are many automated tools (and even a browser) for this type of work... Your question is off topic, website rules is you can't ask for software recommendations

Comment: Hi Dave - I know you are super experienced here - but you're missing the point. I am legitimately trying to solve a Super User type of problem. The answers prove that. I can solve it by the creative use of an existing tool, or take a scripting approach.

Comment: The issue you face may well be on topic - but asking for a tool/add-on is not on topic - see last bullet point: http://superuser.com/help/on-topic The good news is you have an answer :) but I suspect it will be closed in a few days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any kind of form automation tool... or even KeePass, a password safe with autotype feature.

Build your entries in its listing and setup autotype per page title.
Engage Autotype hotkey in the webpage you've set up and it will show you a quick list window, pick an entry and it will fill the form with it.

Or you can do combinations of entries and tabs in one swoop if the form is complex but repeating.

It doesn't require a master password, a db will launch protected and unprotected but if those ID's are private, a short password at the start of the day would ensure they're kept private.

Comment: +1 for some lateral thinking and clever use of KeePass! :) I think that you can create a list of OTPs (One Time Passcodes) that would fit the bill here.

Comment: I definitely love this approach. Very clever!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @JasonXA's excellent answer, you could use the Greasemonkey addon if it is available for your browser choice. This lets you insert Javascript into any web page so you could hack the page to change the text input box into a select input box.

Still think Jason's answer is better though & it will work on any browser, at least on Windows anyway. Use Keepass v2 to get the best capabilities. As a bonus, you get a powerful but easy to use password manager.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about Greasemonkey / Tampermonkey but I don't know if OP knows programming... which is a must for this suggestion.

Comment: True enough Jason though on the other hand he doesn't say he doesn't know how to program either :)

Comment: I wish I could mark both of these answers! I am a developer, so I will use both approaches and see what works best for me. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, please let us know how you get on.